# When do I need to use assume role in terraform verses just AWS_PROFILE

Tags: terraform

Locally I find that I can just use AWS_PROFILE and terraform works fine. But on client environment, it appears even tho I exported AWS_PROFILE, the assumed role appears to be incorrect: (I get some permission issues)

```
AWS_PROFILE=xxx terraform import aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api 00000000
```

I get:

```
+ AWS_PROFILE=xxx
+ terraform import aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api 00000000
[0m[1maws_api_gateway_rest_api.api: Importing from ID "00000000"...[0m
[0m[1m[32maws_api_gateway_rest_api.api: Import complete![0m
[0m[32m  Imported aws_api_gateway_rest_api (ID: 00000000)[0m
[0m[1maws_api_gateway_rest_api.api: Refreshing state... (ID: 00000000)[0m
[31m
[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1maws_api_gateway_rest_api.api (import id: 00000000): 1 error(s) occurred:

* import aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api result: 00000000: aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api: error reading API Gateway REST API (i76an3mk88): AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::0000000000:assumed-role/XXX/i-00000000 is not authorized to perform: apigateway:GET on resource: arn:aws:apigateway:ap-southeast-1::/restapis/00000000
    status code: 403, request id: 00000[0m
```

The client devops suggests using some code like:

```
provider "aws" {
  alias   = "Production"
  version = "~> 1.28"
  region  = "${var.region}"

  assume_role {
    role_arn     = "arn:aws:iam::<redacted>:role/TerraformProductionRole"
  }  
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    encrypt = true
  }
}


terraform import -provider=aws.Production aws_key_pair.prod_ssh_key aws_cccs_prod
```

But I am trying to understand why its required? I doubt it works cos I dont even have the resource `aws_key_pair.prod_ssh_key`?

Comment: This sounds like a question you should ask your client because they seem to have a particular configuration in place already.

Comment: You can use an assume role in a profile as well. But typically you use profile if you are using a Key/Secret, otherwise you use a role if you are using role base authentication or role federation.